# Are there any traditional biographies for Vaishnava Alwars like Periya Puranam is for Shaiva Nayanars?

Tags: vaishnavism, shaivism, nayanar, alvars

I am really interested in learning more about Alvars and Nayanars. While Periya Puranam is a traditional biographies of Nayanars(I read about it online). Are there any such biographies about Alwars?

Comment: Yes. Do you know Tamil ? If so, there are many upanyasam & kalakshepam done by vedic pundits. You can reach out to a local ashram or math to find out.

Comment: @mar no :( I don't know tamil as I am from northern India. Lately I have been really interested in Sri Vaishnavism but dunno where to begin learning about it due to language barrier. Anyway, are there books about alwars?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Upapurana called Bhargava Purana is an ancient biographical text for them. Their stories are foretelled by Narayana. You can check it, [here](https://archive.org/details/YRnM_bhargava-upapuran-akhil-bharatiya-sanskrit-parishad-lucknow/page/n32/mode/1up?view=theater).